# Find Extensionless File in DOS For In Loop

Tags: foreach, dos

I like to find all .js file (for example sss.js)  and file without file type (the extension, the suffix, the file type after .dot)

I tried 
`for ..... In (*,*.js) ....`
But not working, it will go through all files it found.

Please advice how to select the file that no filetype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it correct. You just need a dot after the first asterisk.

```
for ... in (*. *.js) ...
```

Comment: thanks. add a note, `(*.,*.js)` and `(*. *.js)` is same, you can use space or comma to separate different files

Comment: @EricYin - Yes, you can use any combination of `,` `;` `=` `<space>` `<tab>` between the file names :)